# Dual-installation leads to a Windows disk with 1.4MB free space. Is this related to GRUB?

Tags: grub2, windows-10, disk, disk-management

Dual-installation leads to a Windows disk with 1.4MB free space. Is this related to GRUB? Or the Disks app?

[image]

Comment: No, it's a side effect of partition sizes.... You don't see the MBR (*master boot record or sector 0 of a drive*) used by grub as it's outside of the partitioning space, thus won't ever be shown.

Comment: @guiverc What do you mean by "side effect"?

Comment: Binary numbers, disk capacity & partition sizes can result in numbers that don't *fit* into specific bit-sizes used in values in the partition table; meaning small portions of disk can get *wasted* (*it's there, just cannot be allocated to the partition sizes that were selected*).  It's such a tiny portion of the disk space it's not worth worrying about (*and creating different partition sizes usually causes more wastage anyway; even if that tiny space disappears from view & is used*)   Wait and you may get someone who can write an answer better (*more understandable*) than I can

Comment: @guiverc Maybe it's also that only Ubuntu reports it while it may be invisible on Windows?

Comment: You are looking at a disc with a partition of about 256GB. There is a very small amount of the disk that is not in the 256GB partition. the 256GB partition has 230GB free so there are about 26GB of files and stuff on there. You have plenty of space free to use

Comment: Microsoft maybe are *smarter* in hiding this tiny *wasted space*, just to avoid these questions :)    (*A number of us have wasted time trying to re-partition to avoid it, then decided it was wasted effort as I alluded to*)

Comment: @PonJar Yes I know I have plenty of space, but I wanted to understand the cause of the installation seemingly not filling all of the disk.